# Change the stored procedure definer

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a around one hundred stored routines in my MySQL database with with most of them have 'root' as the definer.

I have another mysql account named 'abc', how to change the definer of all routines to 'abc'.

Is it possible to do the same if I have access to MySQL server only as 'abc' user and not as 'root'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know:
You would have to get the script text of them all and drop/recreate them as abc.  You would not be able to do this as abc unless abc has permission to drop/create procedures.

Answer (score 114):

To see the definers:

```
show procedure status;
```

You can change them like this:

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` p SET definer = 'YournewDefiner' WHERE definer='OldDefinerShownBefore'
```

For example:

```
 UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` p SET definer = 'user@%' WHERE definer='root@%'
```

Be careful, because this will change all the definers for all databases.

Comment: "show procedure status" doesn't work for me, but the update does work. Thanks.

Comment: By default DEFINER is creating when i create store procedure in godaddy shared host under mysql db.  Sample: CREATE DEFINER=`sis`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_Login`()   How to remove DEFINER?  Please help me to solve this issue i am breaking my head for last 2 days.

Comment: this saved me after a user cleanup

Comment: Down voted because direct manipulation of the table are not noticed by the server. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//stored-routines-privileges.html)

Comment: While it is unclear whether or how the server stores or accesses the definer, (thanks KDrewiske), it was still a resource for both the command (show) and the table.  Knowing what is wrong is 80% of the battle.

Comment: `UPDATE` changed the table, but `mysqldump` doesn't see it: `mysqldump: Got error: 1449: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist when using LOCK TABLES`. Even after restarting `mysql`. I'm running `mysql-5.5.31`.

Comment: My bad. I had views with a wrong definer either. `update mysql.proc` approach indeed works.

Comment: @KDrewiske And what are the consequences to manipulate the table msql.proc manually? Can you explain with details? Despite contraindicated, the solution is useful.

Comment: @ruzenhack, theoretically `flush tables` would work, my question is why the alias since it isn't used?

Comment: Thanks @bradmace but actually you can refine your SQL with
    and db = 'my_database'
so the complete SQL will be
     UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` p SET definer = 'user@%' WHERE definer='root@%' and db = 'my_database';

Comment: Brief update: it seems that @KDrewiske 's point only applies to mysql 5.5 to 5.7. The version 8.0 documentation no longer mentions this point (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-routines-privileges.html)

Comment: SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS may be MariaDB specific

Comment: This works only after database is restarted. Is there any way to make the server notice the change without restart (similar to "flush privileges" after modifying mysql.user table)?

Comment: Any ideas of what the implications are of manually updating the proc table in a Galera cluster setup? Is it safe to do so or will it break the cluster?

Answer (score 17):

You can update the definer in mysql.proc table against the required table/db...

```
update mysql.proc set definer='root@localhost' where name='t_p';
```

Comment: What is "t_p" in this case?

Comment: @posfan12 `t_p` is the name of the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Export all the procedures of the database `<DB>`:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --no-data --no-create-info --routines \
    --skip-triggers <DB> >routines.sql
```

Edit `routines.sql` and recreate them:

```
cat routines.sql | mysql <DB>
```

Specify `-u` and `-p` switches if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've done mass Definer changes by exporting the database, opening the exported file in a text editor (**not a word processor**) and doing a find and replace trading the new Definer for the old.  I then rename the original database and create a new database with the original database's name.  Just import the modified export file with the new Definer information and you're done.  I like this solution because it gives me a fallback if things go sideways. If something doesn't work, drop the database you created and rename the copy.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem finally solved it using below method.
i got this error: 1449 while inserting the data into table.
solution: go to triggers option there must be some driggers difined by user before drop them from there.
that's it you got the solution now you can make operations on table in phpmydmin

Answer (score 0):

instead use a simple method, create a user (abc) , the grand that user all permissions and in the connection string, connect

with abc. will work finer, the mysql version 8 does not support `mysql`.`proc`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also in this way:

```
update mysql.proc set definer = "root@localhost" where db = "mydatabase";
```

Answer (score -3):

```
alter procedure old_proc_name
delimiter //
create PROCEDURE new_proc_name (parameter)
begin
 Your Sql Statement;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: what an unusual way

Comment: Not a MySQL syntax.