# routines not working in local machine

Tags: mysql

Hi this is my routine in mysqls it working in server but not working in local machine..

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ClassWise_Progress`(IN CLS INT, IN EXM INT)
BEGIN


  // some stuff

END
```

[MySQL error 1449: The user specified as a definer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist)

Comment: 1) The error message seems extremely clear, 2) you're even linking to an answer which solves the problem! What's wrong?!

Comment: I don't think that the linked answer is the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the backtick sign ` as a delimiter, which is used in MySQL to denote names of fields, tables an such. Change it to a single quote ':

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE 'ClassWise_Progress' (IN CLS INT, IN EXM INT)
```

This way MySQL should interpret the strings correctly.

Comment: still same problem @Gerald Schneider

Comment: well, have you checked if the user exists?

Comment: ya,in same db some of routines working fine in local and server but this one not working in local i don't know what i am doing wrong in this?

Comment: Hi frnd my problem is solved. Hello @Gerald Schneider using the backtick sign ` is not a problem we can use that sign if we use a single quote its throw a error.