# user has suddenly no access to a table in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql

So I got this weird problem that started happening today (maybe earlier but only observed today).

One of the reports started having problems. and the PHP is saying my MySQL user has no access. So I tried logging in and it works fine.

I decided to run (using root login)

```
grant all privileges on myschema.* to "myschema"@"localhost;
flush privileges;
```

and still having a problem with the SQL (does selects on multiple tables).

I've run a simple select on the on each of the table involved and apparently, my user doesn't have access to one of the tables.

I tried running the simple select on that table using the root login and this is what I got:

```
mysql> use myschema;
Database changed
mysql> select * from mytable;
ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('myschema'@'10.0.0.%') does not exist
mysql>
```

I still have no problems running selects on other tables.

I found some discussions about the user getting missing (i.e. ERROR 1449) but this isn't the case for me. As I said above, I can login using the user via the mysql command. And I can also see the user when selecting from the user table in mysql database.

Any ideas on what caused it and how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Is `mytable` a view?

Comment: There are lots of answers regarding this error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist I don't know which might apply to your situation

Comment: "definer" mostly refers to views and procedures. I'm not sure what would cause this when accessing a normal table from the mysql> prompt.