# #1055 - Expression of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1055

my Query :

```
select libelle,credit_initial,disponible_v,sum(montant) as montant 
FROM fiche,annee,type where type.id_type=annee.id_type and annee.id_annee=fiche.id_annee 
and annee = year(current_timestamp) GROUP BY libelle order by libelle asc
```

- Mysql 5.7.9 runs the query without any problem but mysql 5.7.12
  display the error above Could you please help me with that

Comment: it is expecting you to have libelle, credit_initila, and disponible_v all in the group by statement

Comment: http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/02/12/why-i-use-only-full-group-by/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting an error in MySql related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/i-am-getting-an-error-in-mysql-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-qu)

Comment: the problem is on mysql itself not the query

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I had a struggle getting this to work i've tested it and it's working on lamp server mysql version 5.12

So, steps to success:

1. `sudo vim /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`
2. Scroll to the bottom of file Copy and paste

   `[mysqld]
   sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

to the bottom of the file

3. save and exit input mode
4. `sudo service mysql restart` to restart MySQL.

Done!

Comment: I resolved the same issue by removing only: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from the sql_mode= string in /etc/mysql/my.cnf in Ubuntu 16.04 (MySQL 5.7) and restarting mysql: systemctl restart mysql

Comment: **For Those Who Cannot Find This File** my file was called **my.ini** is the same as  **mysql.cnf**

Comment: There's some info in the documentation on what's going on here:
[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

And a less drastic way of working around than editing mysql.cnf (or just fixing the sql as gr1zzly be4r and scaisEdge suggested):
[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value)

Comment: You can find the original value by executing this SQL before you change my.cnf: `show global variables like 'sql_mode';`

Comment: I added these settings to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: Don't confuse `[mysqld]` with `[mysql]` as I did.

Comment: It's a good idea to check that you are only changing one setting by running this sql statement first: `SELECT @@sql_mode;`

Comment: This answer is wrong. The correct answer is to fix the query.

Comment: @SalmanA feel free to fix the query and present it to us. by the way  the solution works.

Comment: @deepcell answers below (grizzly bear and drapp) provide the correct fix. Most people unfortunately won't scroll down.

Comment: This is still required for MAMP. :/

Answer (score 74):

This worked for me:

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

You might need sudo for the first step:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: in the end this was the only thing that worked for me too

Comment: I've come to think this solution only persists until mysql is restarted. The accepted solution is better.

Comment: Henry, the advantage this approach has is that it can be applied selectively.  If you modify my.cnf, every app and DB on the server is affected.  OTOH, if the app/account has privileges for SET GLOBAL (which is not assured but can be implemented), you can run this query from the app in the DB preparation phase before other queries are run.  It has saved my bacon with a elderly legacy app that violated FULL_ORDER_GROUP_BY ... I simply call this as soon as the DB connection is initalized ...

Comment: if MySQL is restarted then the issue will arise again. so this is not a permanent fix.

Comment: i use uniserverZero, open console and write that code, now working, thanks

Comment: use SUDO first sudo mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 33):

You need to specify all of the columns that you're not using for an aggregation function in your `GROUP BY` clause like this:

```
select libelle,credit_initial,disponible_v,sum(montant) as montant 
FROM fiche,annee,type where type.id_type=annee.id_type and annee.id_annee=fiche.id_annee 
and annee = year(current_timestamp) GROUP BY libelle,credit_initial,disponible_v order by libelle asc
```

The `full_group_by` mode basically makes you write more idiomatic SQL. You can turn off this setting if you'd like. There are different ways to do this that are outlined in the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Here's MySQL's definition of what I said above:

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If
>   the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default),
>   MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in
>   the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before
>   5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. For a description of
>   pre-5.7.5 behavior, see the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual.)

You're getting the error because you're on a version < 5.7.5

Comment: I'm on ubuntu mysql 5.7.12 any other option available because i have other queries that i need how to turn only full group by of

Comment: This is an actual solution if you are currently writing your db logic, since this will make your code more precise and reduce a lot of uncertainty in your output.

Answer (score 24):

You can disable
**sql_mode=only_full_group_by**
by some command you can try this by terminal or MySql  IDE

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

I have tried this and worked for me.
Thanks :)

Comment: if MySQL is restarted then the issue will arise again. so this is not a permanent fix.

Comment: You could add this statement to your `my.cnf` file to make the setting change permanent.

Answer (score 20):

Solution 1: Remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from mysql console

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

you can read more here

Solution 2: Remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from phpmyadmin

```
Open phpmyadmin & select localhost
Click on menu Variables & scroll down for sql mode
Click on edit button to change the values & remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY & click on save.
```

[image: click here to see image]

Comment: Hi Tauqueer, Please format the mysql line as code. Also you are missing the link referring to additional reading material.

Comment: if MySQL is restarted then the issue will arise again. so this is not a permanent fix.

Comment: SOLUTION IS NOT WORKING

Answer (score 9):

You have to aggregate by anything `NOT IN` the `group by` clause.

So,there are two options...***Add Credit_Initial*** and ***Disponible_v*** to the `group by`

OR

Change them to `MAX( Credit_Initial ) as Credit_Initial, MAX( Disponible_v ) as Disponible_v` if you know the values are constant anyhow and have no other impact.

Comment: THIS is the correct way.   Assigning a name to the Max value was the way to do it, thank you 6 years later

Answer (score 9):

So let's fully understand, Let's say you have a query which works in localhost but does not in production mode, This is because in `MySQL 5.7 and above` they decided to activate the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` by default, basically it is a strict mode which prevents you to select non aggregated fields.

Here's the query (works in local but not in production mode) :

```
SELECT post.*, YEAR(created_at) as year
FROM post
GROUP BY year

SELECT post.id, YEAR(created_at) as year  // This will generate an error since there are many ids
FROM post
GROUP BY year
```

To verify if the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` is activated for, you should execute the following query :

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;   //localhost
```

*Output* : `IGNORE_SPACE, STRICT_TRANS, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`
(If you don't see it, it means it is deactivated)

But if try in production mode, or somewhere where it gives you the error it should be activated:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;   //production
```

*Output:* `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO...`
And it's `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` we're looking for here.

Otherwise, if you are using **phpMyAdmin** then go to -> `Variables` and search for `sql_mode`

Let's take our previous example and adapt it to it :

```
SELECT MIN(post.id), YEAR(created_at) as year  //Here we are solving the problem with MIN()
FROM post
GROUP BY year
```

And the same for `MAX()`

And if we want all the IDs, we're going to need:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(post.id SEPARATOR ','), YEAR(created_at) as year
FROM post
GROUP BY year
```

or another newly added function:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(post.id), YEAR(created_at) as year 
FROM post
GROUP BY year
```

⚠️ ANY_VALUE does not exist for MariaDB

And If you want all the fields, then you could use the same:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(post.id), ANY_VALUE(post.slug), ANY_VALUE(post.content) YEAR(created_at) as year 
FROM post
GROUP BY year
```

❌ To deactivate the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` then you'll need to execute this query:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));
```

Sorry for the novel, hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Base ond defualt config of 5.7.5 ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY 
You  should use all the not aggregate column in your group by

```
select libelle,credit_initial,disponible_v,sum(montant) as montant 
FROM fiche,annee,type 
where type.id_type=annee.id_type 
and annee.id_annee=fiche.id_annee 
and annee = year(current_timestamp) 
GROUP BY libelle,credit_initial,disponible_v order by libelle asc
```

Comment: it does not make any sens, if you count by some id(index pointing to another table), then why would you need to add the other collumns that are not related to the counting in the group by, especialy if you dont want to group by these columns

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds   This is what the clause forces you to do. ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY requires all columns that are not managed by aggregation functions to be declared in the group by  .. thse solution provided  by the OP change the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY  sql_mode but this is not sql correctly (also if is allwed  by mysql until 5.7 by default)

Answer (score 4):

Also if you use MySql 8+ try in console this command:

Open MySql console

```
mysql -u user_name -p
```

And set global SQL mode

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel, you just set `false` in file `database.php`.

```
...
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'strict' => false,
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Same thing is happened with 8.0+ versions as well. By default in 8.0+ version it is "enabled" by default. Here is the link [official document reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

In case of 5.6+, 5.7+ versions, the property "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" is disabled by default.

To disabled it, follow the same steps suggested by @Miloud BAKTETE

Answer (score 0):

just go to the window bottom tray click on wamp icon ,click mysql->my.ini,then there is option ;sql-mode=""
uncomment this make it like sql-mode=""
and restart wamp
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
# This solution work for me:: Centos 7
# sudo vi /etc/my.cnf
Add in your my.cnf file :
sql_mode = ""
```

Make sure to restart server, in order to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you change your

> sql_mode=only_full_group_by

unless you know what you are doing.

Not putting all the aggregating columns into the **group by** is technically wrong, and can produce unexpected results.  If you are someone that doesn't know that this is poor practice, it would be better to learn why this is poor practice and avoid it.  Not to mention, if you start writing SQL for most other DBMS they won't let you write these types of queries either.