# MySQL : Group by Datetime (Hour - Day - Month - Year)

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have this form of table
[image]

i wanna Count insertions which have the type = "non_repondu" and group the results by 3 criteria.

> 1-client_id
>
> 2-queue_id
>
> and
>
> **3- datetime : by hour , day , by month and by year**

So far i have done this:

```
SELECT `client_id`,`queue_id`,`datetime`,COUNT(`type`)
AS nombre_appels_repondus
FROM `appels`
where `type`= "non_repondu" 
group by `appels`.`client_id`,`appels`.`queue_id`,`appels`.`datetime
```

[image]

> but like that i have just filtered by the full datetime column which results me
> a table of every unique datetime line separately  , how can i get result by hour
> , day , month and year ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [DATE_FORMATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in group By clause. Hope it should be solved your problem

```
SELECT
    `client_id`,
    `queue_id`,
    `datetime`,
    COUNT(`type`) AS nombre_appels_repondus
FROM
    `appels`
WHERE
    `type` = "non_repondu"
GROUP BY
    `appels`.`client_id`,
    `appels`.`queue_id`,
    DATE_FORMAT(
        `appels`.`datetime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H');
```

**OR**

If you want to add in your selected column list with **day, month, year and hour** then please try this one

```
SELECT
    `client_id`,
    `queue_id`,
    `datetime`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`appels`.`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DAY,
    DATE_FORMAT(`appels`.`datetime`, '%Y-%m') AS MONTH,
    DATE_FORMAT(`appels`.`datetime`, '%Y') AS YEAR,
    DATE_FORMAT(`appels`.`datetime`, '%H') AS HOUR,
    COUNT(`type`) AS nombre_appels_repondus
FROM
    `appels`
WHERE
    `type` = "non_repondu"
GROUP BY
    `appels`.`client_id`,
    `appels`.`queue_id`,
    DATE_FORMAT(
        `appels`.`datetime`,
        '%Y-%m-%d %H'
    );
```

Comment: #1055 - Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'asterisk_bi.appels.datetime' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: follow this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951742/1055-expression-of-select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggr. hope it should be solve your problem

Comment: i working on a distant server which i cannot modify , but i solver it by doing this :   ANY_VALUE(`datetime`),
    DATE_FORMAT(ANY_VALUE(`appels`.`datetime`), '%d') AS DAY,
                      (you can update your answer to eventuals visitors)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more exact with your group by statement

```
SELECT `client_id`,`queue_id`,`datetime`,COUNT(`type`)
AS nombre_appels_repondus
FROM `appels`
WHERE `type`='non_repondu'
GROUP BY `appels`.`client_id`,
    `appels`.`queue_id`,
    YEAR(`appels`.`datetime`) ,
    MONTH(`appels`.`datetime`),
    DAY(`appels`.`datetime`),
    HOUR(`appels`.`datetime`)
```

Comment: i got this error :#1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'asterisk_bi.appels.datetime' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: See the second answer (the more upvoted one) to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by on how to disable only_full_group_by mode @firasKoubaa

Comment: i have used this to depass that problem :  ANY_VALUE(`datetime`)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
YEAR(datetime), MONTH(datetime), DAY(datetime), HOUR(datetime),
client_id, queue_id, COUNT(type) AS nombre_appels_repondus
FROM appels
WHERE type = "non_repondu"
GROUP BY YEAR(datetime), MONTH(datetime), DAY(datetime), HOUR(datetime), 
client_id, queue_id;
```

Comment: Can you add some context that explain how this will solve the problem in question, instead of code-only answer