# MySQL: Group By Max Value Returns Duplicate Results

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have below `customer` table with max qty.

**I need a unique user who has max qty order by its group id.**

Input:

```
id, customer_id, customer_group_id   qty
1      1              3               1
2      1              3               10
3      1              3               5
4      2              2               10
5      2              2               1  
6      2              2               2 
7      3              1               5 
8      3              1               10
9      4              4               1
10     4              4               2
11     4              4               2
```

Output should be:

```
id, customer_id, customer_group_id, qty
11     4             4               2
10     4             4               2 - This should be not selected
2      1             3               10
4      2             2               10
8      3             1               10
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
WHERE qty IN ( SELECT MAX(qty) FROM customer GROUP BY customer_id) 
ORDER BY customer_group_id DESC;
```

I tried above query but seems not working.

Comment: Please check you mysql version there may be issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951742/1055-expression-of-select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggr

Comment: Nope @Shibon that is not the case. I have updated question. Please check