# Transfer Zend App to new VPS show blank page

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, zend-framework, vps

I bought a new VPS and I try to transfer my working ZendApp (work in previous hosting with DirectAdmin). Now i install nginx with php5 and mysql i this is my php configuration - works well

http://178.216.200.85/info.php

I turn on display errors in php.ini and it shows me error in writable /_cache/ folder soo i set it to 777 permission. Error resolved but i still have error and don't see anything in my site http://178.216.200.85/index.php

I don't have any .htaccess file

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-avaible/default content

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 178.216.200.85;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

What i should to add or someting to run my app in new server?

Any advice will be very valuable

Comment: Can you add the error itself with `error_reporting(-1);` ?

Comment: Not sure can you share the directory structure? may be this is due to location try changing like this: `location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/usr/local/zend/tmp/php-fastcgi.socket;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
  }`

Comment: @mim where i should add Your code?

Comment: @TomekR your projects index.php or you can turn on errors on your configuration ini.

Comment: @ShahrozeNawaz with Your code i have 502 Bad Gateway error in root and in /info.php file

Comment: @mim. I add Your code to index.php file and still blank page. Could You check my php config? Maybe i missed some libary http://178.216.200.85/info.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem (General error: 1449) occurs when you access views, triggers, or procedures, for example, when you move a database, when a connection to a new location occurs on behalf of another user.

You have created some data under a certain user ('bunga'@'localhost'), which is not currently on the new server in MySQL. The easiest way is to create this user.

Learn More — [MySQL error 1449: The user specified as a definer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist)