# Homebrew, MySQL 8 support

Tags: mysql, version-control, homebrew, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

Anyone have the inside scoop on when Homebrew will be updated to support MySQL 8's first general release (8.0.11)? I can't seem to find it by searching, but I bet someone here knows :)

Comment: ++ following...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Homebrew pushed MySQL 8.0.11 as an upgrade yesterday (Wed, 13 June 2018). I thought I had it pinned, but no such luck.

It's a total disaster:

MySQL 8.0.11 uses `caching_sha2_password` as the default authentication method (leave it to Oracle to do something like this in a point release, but there you have it).

So far, it breaks everything I've tried: phpMyAdmin, Nextcloud, and WordPress.

I'll be rolling back to 5.7.22 later today.

*Update 17 June 2018 6:50PM CDT*:

**Three step solution**:

1. Add to `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf` file (found in `/usr/local/etc/` for Homebrew's installation):

   ```
   default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
   ```
2. At shell prompt:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p

   > ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'
      IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
      BY '[password]';

   > exit
   ```
3. Reboot server

   ```
   brew services restart mysql
   ```

[Short version solution](https://www.farces.com/wrestling-with-the-mysql-8-0-11-bear/)

[Long version solution](https://www.farces.com/wikis/naked-server/mysql/)

*Update 18 June 2018 11:53PM CDT*:

The solution provided above is partial, at best. In my experience MySQL 8.0.11 is not nearly ready for production (or even development) use.

Comment: It is complete insanity that brew rolled out 8.0 as upgrade to 5.7.

Comment: since 8.0 cannot be downgraded to 5.7 without having backup of database prior to upgrade. also, update did not check if my database/tables can run under 8.0. as suggested in 8.0 upgrade scenarios https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-strategies.html

`mysqlcheck -u root -p --all-databases --check-upgrade`

by running this, brew could easily see that my db cannot work on 8.0, before it did the upgrade.

Comment: I had the luck to be able to roll back and keep all my databases intact with `brew remove mysql` and `brew install mysql@5.7`.

Comment: I didn't have any joy rolling back after the 8.x upgrade, but fortunately I had a Time Machine backup of `/usr/local/var/mysql` from which I was able to restore. After removing MySQL 8 (`brew remove mysql`) and then installing 5.7 again (`brew install mysql@5.7`) as directed above it's working again.

Comment: I've been dinking with this all day after everything exploded when I updated Brew. I don't want anything to do with MySQL 8 so I ran the brew remove mysql command and then brew install mysql@5.7 which gives me 5.7 back, but when I try to log into it via the command line using mysql -uroot, I get the following error. It's maddening. Any ideas on what might be going on here?


ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: After installing mysql@5.7, I can't run the mysql client. Seems like even when installing old versions, the binaries should stay the same.

Comment: @BeesonBison Can you be more specific? I have what I knew was a working `/usr/local/var/mysql` in a disk image that predates the upgrade. Are you saying I can brew remove everything related to mysql, `brew reinstall mysql@5.7` and then copy the working `/usr/local/var/mysql` from the image to the same path on my running instance. I assume mysql can't be running during the copy process. What about ownership and permissions of both the mysql directory and its contents.

Comment: @JohnD. yes that's correct, just make sure you stop MySQL before you copy over from your disk image and then restart it afterwards. That's all I did. RE: ownership, I think it should be `yourusername:admin` and chmod 755 should be fine for permissions. I'm not an expert on that though so someone else might be able to advise?

Comment: @BeesonBison Thank you _very_ much! That worked perfectly and I was able to dump out the tables successfully. I did a full removal of all traces of MySQL, both homebrew and some existing direct installations. I renamed the original `/usr/local/var/mysql` directory to `mysql-old` and then did `brew install mysql@5.7`. After starting and stopping the service I renamed `/usr/local/var/mysql` to `mysql-new` and then renamed the old one to the to `mysql`. Starting up took a long time but it worked.

Comment: I rebuilt all my databases from dumps on a previous machine while setting up a new environment with 8.0.11, and rolling back was not smooth when the databases were created with 8.0.11. Had to scrap them to get 5.7 rolling.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this, I thought I was going mad trying to get this working properly. As another possible workaround if this doesn't work (not entirely sure why, sorry), I've switched to using a docker container for 5.7.24 and had no problems, but I would never have believed that this is what Homebrew did without your answer here. I'm switching to use docker containers over brew installing things wherever possible as a result of this, it's completely ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to overcome this without removing my all database which from mysql version 5.7.

First, simply upgrade database with this command

```
mysql_upgrade -u root
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51486493/2342289

Last. Install sequel-pro-nightly. I need this because i can browse my db from the command but not from sequal-pro. So, luckily the nightly sequel-pro works.

```
   brew cask install sequel-pro-nightly
```

Then, boom. Everything is back. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

It's waiting to be merged into homebrew-core.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/27210

Answer (score 2):

1. Removed MySql using the steps on [this site](https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d).
2. Do `brew install mysql@5.7`.
3. Go to [this site](https://medium.com/@jainakansha/installing-and-running-mysql-on-macos-with-errors-resolved-70ef53e3b5b9) and follow the instructions starting at step 4.
4. Be sure to find out if the paths on step 5 actually exist on your machine. The paths listed on that site didn't work for me. I had to find them on my own. Start by looking in `/usr/local` and search out the mysql folder from there and dig until you find the files he has listed.

I stopped at step 7 because I was able to take it from there. Hopefully, you can as well.