# Cannot establish a connection with MySQL running on MacOS

Tags: mysql, wordpress, macos, homebrew

My MySQL appears to not be running correctly on my MacOS Catalina (10.15) according to Homebrew and according to my wordpress app, it cannot make a connection to my MySQL server. When I try to read a database in a [SQL Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) SQL Pro cannot establish a connection either. However, I can log into MySQL using my terminal shell which is confusing to me.

What is wrong with my MySQL process? MySQL was working fine for my wordpress app yesterday. The only difference was that I restarted my computer and now, I cannot seem to start it successfully with homebrew and wordpress cannot establish a connection to it. Here is a break down of details and logs with regards to wordpress and homebrew

### Wordpress

Yesterday, I restarted my laptop running on MacOS and when after restarting my computer I tried to run my wordpress app locally, but wordpress complained about an error establishing a database connection:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Unexpected server response while doing caching_sha2 auth: 109 in /Users/robskrob/code/projects/myblog/wordpress/web/wp/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1633

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in /Users/robskrob/code/projects/kingandpartners/myblog/wordpress/web/wp/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1633
MySQL server has gone away

Error establishing a database connection
This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at 127.0.0.1. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
Are you sure you have typed the correct hostname?
Are you sure the database server is running?
If you’re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress Support Forums.
```

### MySQL Homebrew logs

I checked what I believe to be my log file for the mysql homebrew installation in `/usr/local/var/mysql/Roberts-MBP-4.fios-router.home.err` -- these are the logs from today:

```
2020-01-17T23:59:48.010069Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 2098009ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2020-01-18T00:32:58.010992Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 1937613ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2020-01-18T02:26:25.009708Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 6753733ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2020-01-18T03:15:04.012850Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 2868086ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2020-01-18T03:17:10.403347Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 113439ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2020-01-18T04:19:50.025641Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2020-01-18T04:19:50.026067Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2020-01-18T04:19:50.026406Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2020-01-18T04:19:50.026859Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-01-18T04:19:50.028486Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-01-18T04:19:50.266455Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.266534Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.266547Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.266558Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.266566Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.278568Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.278607Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.278712Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284742Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284768Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284780Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284789Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284796Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284803Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284810Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284817Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284824Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284831Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284838Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284846Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284855Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284863Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284870Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284877Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284884Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284891Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284898Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284906Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284913Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284920Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284930Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284937Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284944Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284964Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284980Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284987Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.284994Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.285009Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-01-18T04:19:50.302153Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-01-18T04:19:50.302324Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-01-18T04:19:50.448900Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-18T04:19:50.455916Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200117 23:19:50
2020-01-18T04:19:51.352113Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 26072066420
2020-01-18T04:19:51.354829Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-01-18T04:19:51.354892Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-01-18T04:19:51.355317Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-01-18T04:19:51.355373Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-01-18T04:19:51.355402Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-01-18T04:19:51.356443Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-01-18T04:19:51.364593Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2020-01-18T04:21:20.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/Roberts-MBP-4.fios-router.home.err'.
2020-01-18T04:21:21.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2020-01-18T04:21:22.464837Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 773
2020-01-18T04:21:23.267083Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2020-01-18T04:21:24.347624Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2020-01-18T04:22:10.697989Z 2 [System] [MY-011003] [Server] Finished populating Data Dictionary tables with data.
2020-01-18T04:22:12.302757Z 5 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '50700' to '80018' started.
2020-01-18T04:22:20.760953Z 5 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '50700' to '80018' completed.
2020-01-18T04:22:20.869345Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-01-18T04:22:20.901909Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew.
2020-01-18T04:22:21.087121Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/tmp/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-01-18T18:40:40.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/Roberts-MBP-4.fios-router.home.err'.
2020-01-18T18:40:40.6NZ mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
2020-01-18T18:40:42.139017Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  Homebrew.
2020-01-18T18:40:50.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/Roberts-MBP-4.fios-router.home.err'.
2020-01-18T18:40:50.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2020-01-18T18:40:50.703294Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 15000
2020-01-18T18:40:50.709793Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2020-01-18T18:40:51.867098Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-01-18T18:40:51.893469Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew.
2020-01-18T18:40:52.023790Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/tmp/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-01-18T18:53:44.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/Roberts-MBP-4.fios-router.home.err'.
2020-01-18T18:53:44.6NZ mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
2020-01-18T18:53:45.316518Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  Homebrew.
2020-01-18T18:53:54.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/Roberts-MBP-4.fios-router.home.err'.
2020-01-18T18:53:54.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2020-01-18T18:53:55.004674Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 17779
2020-01-18T18:53:55.011065Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2020-01-18T18:53:57.547543Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-01-18T18:53:57.573755Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew.
2020-01-18T18:53:57.706901Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/tmp/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

### Brew Services List

When I run `brew services list` I see that `mysql` has the status `error`:

```
$ brew services list
Name              Status  User     Plist
chromedriver      stopped
docker-machine    stopped
elasticsearch     started robskrob /Users/robskrob/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist
elasticsearch@2.4 stopped
httpd             stopped
mysql             error   robskrob /Users/robskrob/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
nginx             stopped
php               started robskrob /Users/robskrob/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
postgresql        stopped
rabbitmq          stopped
redis             started robskrob /Users/robskrob/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

### MySQL Terminal Session

I am able to enter a `mysql` console session in my zshell:

```
$ mysql -uroot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 8.0.18 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show tables;
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
mysql> use myblog_development;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
```

This tells me that to a certain extent it appears that `mysql` is running, but my wordpress app cannot establish a connection to it.

### System.log

When I printed out the system log on my machine, I see these strange logs regarding `mysql`:

```
Jan 18 13:53:44 Roberts-MBP-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql[14913]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Jan 18 13:53:44 Roberts-MBP-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Jan 18 13:53:44 Roberts-MBP-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql[17411]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Jan 18 13:53:44 Roberts-MBP-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

### Homebrew forum

There appears to be a similarly [logged issue](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/brew-services-list-shows-mysql-in-the-error-state-but-mysql-is-running-correctly/5328) in homebrew forums.

### Update 1

Following the instructions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304157/homebrew-mxcl-mysql2274-service-could-not-initialize-unable-to-set-current) I ran these commands to see if mysql's running state would improve:

```
$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
/Users/robskrob/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist: Operation now in progress
$  launchctl remove ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
$ rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

As a result when I run `brew services list` I now see `mysql` in a better status -- `mysql` went from `error` to `started` and has stayed at `started:`
mysql             started robskrob /Users/robskrob/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`

However, wordpress still cannot make a connection to mysql.

The new logs for `mysql` from System.log are:

```
Jan 18 14:36:05 Roberts-MBP-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Jan 18 14:48:44 Roberts-MBP-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was on Mysql 8.X.X -- I found [this issue](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2699) and began to believe that my version of MySQL was too advanced. Using [this guide](https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d) for reference, I deleted my version of MySQL and deleted all the MySQL databases. Then I installed with homebrew `mysql@5.7` and followed the post install instructions so that my shell had `mysql` in its `PATH`. After installing `mysql@5.7` successfully I restarted my MacOS. Then I created the mysql database my wordpress app uses and seeded this database with some data.

With a fresh install of `mysql@5.7` and some boiler data in my database that my wordpress app uses, wordpress was able to establish a connection with `mysql`.

### Update:

I just thought I would post here that apparently there has been issues with upgrading to homebrew's `mysql` 8.x.x:

1. [How to revert from mysql 8.0.11 to a specific older version such as 5.7.21?](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-revert-from-mysql-8-0-11-to-a-specific-older-version-such-as-5-7-21/2431)
2. [Homebrew, MySQL 8 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126503/homebrew-mysql-8-support)