# ERROR 1449 (HY000): problem encountered while issuing commands like 'show databases', 'show tables' etc. in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

## SQL Commands like: show databases, show tables not working in MySQL Server 8

Hi, guys I have set up MySql Server 8 for my java project on Ubuntu 18.04 Possibly I am missing out something while upgrading from MySql server 5.7. Although I am using it any how but cannot issue some of the commands:
show databases, show tables etc.

```
mysql> show databases;
ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist
mysql> show tables;
ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist
```

output:

```
ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error 1449: The user specified as a definer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist)

Comment: something went wrong with your upgrade. Please post how you done it.

Answer (score 1):

The error has been fixed after this command:

```
sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```