# ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to list all tables from mysql database on ubuntu os. But I am getting this error all time;

```
mysql> use mysql;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist
```

I have checked my mysql version:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.20 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

So it seems it is last version of mysql.

How can I fix this error?

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error 1449: The user specified as a definer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist)

Comment: Not. It gives same error when I run the ALTER statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs when there is any view / trigger in that database (mysql in your case) that has a definer (in other words a user) that is a definer for the view but then the user itself doesnt exists. A fresh install of mysql should have that user

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user where user='mysql.infoschema';
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

With the permissions :

```
mysql> show grants for 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost';
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mysql.infoschema@localhost                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `mysql.infoschema`@`localhost` |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For some reason that user is missing / deleted in your users list and is why when you list tables its also checking for views in it and complaining about its missing definer.

**Solution :**

Simply create the user with the permissions above and that should stop showing the error.

Create user:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Grant permissions:

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `mysql.infoschema`@`localhost`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I tried. Getting like this:mysql> show grants for 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost';
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'mysql.infoschema' on host 'localhost'
mysql> CREATE USER 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost'
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `mysql.infoschema`@`localhost`;
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
mysql>

Comment: What is the user you logged in as.. ? probably you do not have permissions. I would login as root that has every permission and I replicated your issue to ensure the solution I suggested works fine. you can find the user you are logged in as using `select user()` and grants using `show grants`

You usually get that error if you are trying to using GRANT to create a user and grant permissions at the same time since Mysql 8. Try separate commands, fist to create user and then to add grants.

Comment: Interesting @kodcu, can you show the output of the command `mysql> show grants\G;`

Comment: mysqld --upgrade=FORCE 
helps

Answer (score 36):

1. [Delete the problematic user](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-manage-mysql-databases-and-users-from-the-command-line/#:%7E:text=set%20(0.00%20sec)-,Delete%20MySQL%20user%20account,USER%20%27database_user%40%27localhost%27%3B)

```
DROP USER 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost';
```

The rest of the solution is like previous answers.

2. Create the user again
3. Grant it permissions

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

mysql> GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `mysql.infoschema`@`localhost`;
```

Comment: Worked for me too! Grant select is refused with error "ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT mysql" in case I attempt it on the existing problematic user. But if following this answer, delete it, create new one, grant permissions - all works.

Comment: What password do I set it to?

Comment: Hey @User

You can use any password within the single quotes, a string password of your own related to this user.

Comment: I have tried tons of solutions only this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I transfered my users table from another mysql server to a new installation and ran into this error. So, if you don't have the `mysql.infoschema` user, you can try:

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql

sudo mysqld --upgrade=FORCE
```

This fixed for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer, IMO.

Comment: After a painful 4 hours I find an answer with one vote that works. All I had to do extra is `sudo systemctl start mysql` after the aforementioned process

Comment: This fixed my issues. Hats down

Comment: This worked for me, This issue is also caused by imported DBs, Your imports should only import other tables besides mysql... mysql table changes overide your current one

Answer (score 4):

After lots of attempt，the solution is delete user `mysql.infoschema` first and then do **vamshi's** steps:

**Create user**:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Grant permissions:

mysql> GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `mysql.infoschema`@`localhost`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 1;
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

source https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-1449-hy000-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-mysqlinfoschema-at-localhost-does-not-exist?signup

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I migrated from Mysql 5.7 to Mysql 8.0. The problem was that I had used mysqldump --all-databases, which created an sql file that included the "mysql" table and some #innodb_tmp table.

The result is that when I imported it to Mysql 8.0, it dropped and recreated the Mysql 8.0 "mysql" table, corrupting everything in the process, including deleting the 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' user, which is normally set up during the mysql installation.

After a clean re-install of Mysql, I edited the dumped sql file, carefully removing the "mysql" and "#innodb_tmp" tables, and then imported the databases from scratch. That fixed the problem.