# mysql can't be accessed after windows restart?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I made a mysql db locally hosted last night and now I can't access it after a windows restart. During setup I made it use legacy auth and also made it start as a windows service.

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the instructions listed in the message you posted? Specifically, are you **sure** that the MySQL service is running?

Comment: I have no clue how to do so

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127983/error-1449-hy000-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-mysql-infoschemalocalho)

Answer (score 0):

try close windows firewalld and sure your mysql service is up