# MySQL 8.0.22 The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist

Tags: mysql

I do understand that this has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist), however, I've had trouble figuring out how to fix this issue for MySQL 8.0.22 (all the suggested fixes do not seem to work as the `mysql.proc` table does not exist in MySQL 8.0.22).

I am able to do any CRUD operations with my user but as soon as I run:

```sh
mysql -u myuser -ppassword < data.sql
```

I get

```
ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 19: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist
```

I have checked that I have been granted all permissions. How can I change the DEFINER to `'myuser'@'localhost'` rather than `'root'@'%'`?

Comment: Neither ALTER FUNCTION nor ALTER PROCEDURE allows to change the definer. So simply edit your .SQL file and replace the definer account with one you need, then import.

Comment: The SQL file that I am using has no definer in it, it only has some insert statements. Are you saying I should add the definer?

Comment: If so then there exists some compound statement (function or trigger) defined by removed account. Re-create them. Recommendation: create mentioned account, get compound ststements codes, create separate account with enough privileges but without login privilege and recreate these statements using this account.

Comment: Ahh yep there was some stray tiggers that didn't allow the prevented some of my inserts - once fixed all seems good. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
 GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```