# nodejs sequelize mysql async transaction FailedSequelizeDatabaseError The user specified as a definer ldgybxav_ph1_admin@49.37.47.142 does not exist

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

When ever I am trying to use asynchronous transaction in by node js app it is giving me an error during post request that user does not exist. But the same user credentials is working fine if I do a simple get or post from the same server and db.

```
router.post('/medicineretailsalereturn', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Medicine Retail Return Calls......");
    console.log(req.body);
    var sequelize = common.setPharmaDBConn4SQL(req.headers['pharma_id']);
    const t = await sequelize.transaction();
    try {
        req.body.bill.med_sale_date = new Date();
        req.body.bill.med_bill_number = billgenerator(3);
        req.body.bill.record_created_date = new Date();
        var medicineSellBill = await MedicineRetailSaleBill.create(req.body.bill, { transaction: t });
        for (var medCount = 0; medCount < req.body.items.length; medCount++) {
            var sellReturnJSON = req.body.items[medCount];
            sellReturnJSON.med_bill_id = medicineSellBill.med_sale_bill_id;
            sellReturnJSON.record_created_date = new Date();
            if(sellReturnJSON.med_bill_number != null) sellReturnJSON.med_sell_bill_number = sellReturnJSON.med_bill_number;
            
            if(sellReturnJSON.med_bill_number == null) {
                sellReturnJSON.med_bill_number = medicineSellBill.med_bill_number;
                console.log("Sell Deatils");
                console.log(sellReturnJSON);
                await MedicineRetailSaleDetails.create(sellReturnJSON, { transaction: t });
            } else {
                sellReturnJSON.med_bill_number = medicineSellBill.med_bill_number;
                console.log("Sell Retun Deatils");
                console.log(sellReturnJSON);
                await MedicineRetailReturnDetails.create(sellReturnJSON, { transaction: t });
            }
        }
        await t.commit();
        res.status(200).send("Medicine Reatils Sell/Return Bill Number :" + medicineSellBill.med_bill_number);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error :" + error)
        await t.rollback();
        res.status(200).send("Medicine Reatils Sell/Return Failed" + error);
    }
});
```

I can share the entire code if needed. Any help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: Did you check the mysql user write permission on the specified table?

Comment: yes the user is having all privileges in this database .. I am using milesweb remote mysql db

Comment: I guess this user is really dropped after creating the table which is touched inside the transaction. If you know what I mean could you have a check for such a case?  you can use select * from mysql.users to see the user list

Comment: The user is not dropped as I am able to do a get as well as post request using it. Only problem happening while I try to use the above post request.

Comment: ldgybxav_ph1_admin@49.37.47.142 user and ldgybxav_ph1_admin@127.0.0.1 are different for mysql i guess

Comment: ldgybxav_ph1_admin is the user ... I am connecting to remote db in MilesWeb that is why the ip is 49.37.47.142 and not 127.0.0.1 ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist