# Mysql database: EXISTING user is considered as 'not exists'

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am on localhost with a mysql database and logged in as root.
then I added a user 'HPtigermak' with ALL prvileges which is done correctly when I open query

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

But when I try to add a view with this user as definer it says:

```
Error 1449: The user specified as a definer ('HPtigermak'@'%') does not exist
```

I also tried to replace 'HPtigermak' with 'root' to create this view but same error message:

```
Error 1449: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist
```

Very strange as this is the root user!

Whats incorrect or whats the reason for that?

Comment: is it `root@localhost`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error 1449: The user specified as a definer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist)

Comment: I found the reason although the reason is not clear to my at all: 
User 'HPtigermak'@'%' is not equal 'HPtigermak'@'localhost' !!!

All tables, SPs, views, function received from dump only 'HPtigermak'@'%' and I can use them on localhost.
But I cannot copy a view for example with the definer 'HPtigermak'@'%' to create it on localhost. Then I can only use the select without the definer and settings.

Answer (score 0):

The issue 'HPtigermak'@'%' versus 'HPtigermak'@'localhost' gets more and more weird to me:

In an imported function (from dump) I find the definer 'HPtigermak'@'%'.
I can run the function WITHOUT an error but NO result. Workbench message is: OK

Using any function with definer 'HPtigermak'@'%' in a VIEW leads to an error, same with every SP run with or without using a function inside.

But I can ALTER the definer from a newly created object to user 'HPtigermak'@'%' who is considered to 'NOT EXISTS'. Very confusion this behaviour.

So I need to change the dump file without a definer statement and restore it again.
or I change all objects to the user 'HPtigermak'@'localhost'.

The only objects which can be edited in design are tables, although created with definer 'HPtigermak'@'%'.